# Coprimality of $2^n + 3^n$ and $5^n + 7^n$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

Prove or disprove that for all positive integers $n$, $2^n +3^n$ and $5^n + 7^n$ are always coprime.

This is not a homework problem, it is merely a problem I set myself after doing some number theory drills.

I tried multiplying $2^n +3^n$ by $5^n$, and $5^n + 7^n$ by $2^n$. Then, I subtracted both to deduce that the gcd divides $15^n - 14^n$. But I don't know if this helps at all.

Comment: Here are the first few values of $\gcd(2^n+3^n, 5^n + 7^n)$ :$2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 11, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 79, 1, 11, 1, 1, 37, 1, 1$. I don't expect there is a pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$2^5+3^5$ is divisible by $11$. So is $5^5+7^5$.

Comment: That was a good one! I suspected that they were coprime because Wolfram said so... http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=gcd%282%5En%2B3%5En%2C+5%5En+%2B+7%5En%29&x=0&y=0

Comment: I guess not using Alpha has advantages. It was a natural candidate, because $5=(11-1)/2$.